# Is there an inflection point in this diagram?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I am learning machine learning and statistics in python. I have plotted sample data and fitted a regression line:

[image]

The author says that there is an inflection point between week 3 and week 4. Please correct me if I am wrong, isn't an inflection point the point where the curve switches from being concave to convex and vice-versa? If so, I don't see it happening in this graph. Does someone see it? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think his choice of definition for "inflection point" is a "drastic change in the curve's shape"

Comment: @Alex Thanks! That's what I was thinking as well, but I just wanted to be sure. :)